# Simplest explanation of a limit for a calc I student

Tags: calculus, limits, education

I had a calculus I student come to my office hours with the following problem:
Suppose $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^2}=L$. Find $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{x-a}$. I sifted through my real analysis bag of tricks to find a solution for them but unfortunately it seemed to go beyond the scope of their class. If anyone has any pedagogical advice on how to explain this problem to a calculus I student, that would be great!

Comment: Isn't it just $0$ by multiplying through by $x-a$, which will tend to $0$?

Comment: Near $a,$ $\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^2}\approx L$ implies $\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)}\approx L(x-a).$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just an elementary limit law.  You've assumed that $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^2}$ exists and is equal to $L$. Then
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a} \left(\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^2} \cdot (x-a) \right)= \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^2} \cdot \lim_{x \to a}(x-a) = L\cdot 0 =0.
$$

Comment: Elegant solution!

Comment: thank you so much!! I overcomplicated it far too much... I need to think more simply first